# relative path for a MATLAB program called via the search path

Tags: matlab, user-interface, relative-path

I wrote a MATLAB program with a GUI (to enter the measurement settings) and a measurement function which gets called when pressing "START" in the GUI. 
In both I use separate files for sub functions to keep it easier to read and maintain.

The file structure looks something like this

```
C:/../folder/+measure/measure.m  
C:/../folder/+measure/getData.m  
C:/../folder/+measure/plot.m   
C:/../folder/+measure/evalutate.m

C:/../folder/+measureGUI/getGuiData.m  
C:/../folder/+measureGUI/calcLimits.m  
C:/../folder/+measureGUI/saveGuiState.m  
C:/../folder/+measureGUI/loadGuiState.m    
C:/../folder/+measureGUI/background.png
C:/../folder/+measureGUI/guiState.mat

C:/../folder/measureGUI.fig  
C:/../folder/measureGUI.m
```

This works, if I'm executing the measureGUI.m in "folder".

The current settings in the GUI are saved in the `guiState.mat` file when closing the GUI in `saveGuiState.m`

```
filename = '+autoProberGUI/guiState.mat';
save(filename, 'guiState');
```

And loaded (by `loadGuiState.m`) the next time the GUI gets opened.

Now I have to put the finished program on a network drive and add the folder to my matlab search path to call `measureGUI.m`.
The program works but it can't save or load the guiState.mat due to the relative path (I guess the path is relative to the folder I'm currently in, and not the folder the calling function is in).

I think I could include the subfolder to the search path or use an absolute path in `filename`. But both solutions seem to me to be not the proper way.

Is there a way to have relative paths to the file from where the function is located on the drive? Meaning relative to

```
I:/..NetworkDrive../folder/+measureGUI/saveGuiState.m
```

instead of relative from where I call `measureGUI.m`

(Sorry for the poor English, I hope it is not too confusing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pwd` to get the full path to you current working directory.
Then you can concatenate with `[pwd '/folder/+measureGUI/saveGuiState.m']`.

To locate the function you can use `which`.

Comment: I used that before, but don't need the path to the working directory. I need the path to the place where the function is stored in (on the network drive).

Comment: `which` will return the full path to a function.

Comment: perfect, that's what I was looking for